# Reactor Flux<MyObject> to Mono<List<MyObject>>

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, reactive-streams

How can I convert `Flux<MyObject>` directly to `Mono<List<MyObject>>` ?

I am looking for equivalent of `Single<List<MyObject>> single = observable.toList()` from RxJava.

With blocking operator I can do it like this:

`val just: Mono<List<MyObject>> = Mono.just(flux.toIterable().toList())`

But it is executed at the time of declaration which doesn't seam to be right.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Flux` has the method [`collectList()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--) doing just the same like `toList()` in Rx.

```
val just: Mono<List<MyObject>> = flux.collectList()
```