# How to get Flux or List from two Flux(Object) in Spring Reactive Programming?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I am new to Spring Reactive Project. In my Spring Boot Controller class I have

> `Flux<House>  ( list of all houses in the database)  and Flux<Image>`

coming from service layer where given `Flux<Image>` are images for a given House like a list of houses each of which has its own collection of images. That means that I have to iterate over `Flux<House>` to get id of the home and then call findByHouseId on Image to get `Flux<Image>` , each Image has houseId property.  Each image object has a property "cover" with string value "yes" or "no" and another property "type" having various string values like "bedroom". I want to collect a

```
list of Flux<Image> like List<Flux<Image>> or List<List<Image>>
```

containing only those Images for which "cover" == "yes" OR "type" == "bedroom". How to achieve this?  Programming code will answer this question.

Below was attempted as part of the solution but even this  partial solution does not work:

```
List<Flux<Image>> imagesList= new ArrayList<Flux<Image>>();
        Flux<House> houses = houseService.findAllHouses();

        houses.map(house ->  house.getId()).subscribe(id -> imageService.findByHouseId(id))
        .map(imageFlux ->imagesList.add(imageFlux));
```

Please note that I am looking for solution that does not involve invoking block() ( negating the benefit of being reactive) unless this is the only way.

In non-reactive situation this is what I want:

```
List<House> houses  --> List of all houses
Map<String,List<Image>> mapOfImages  --> where key is houseId
```

so for each house I can easily get images for that house while iterating over houses in view template.

These (houses and mapOfImages) will be passed to model like

```
model.addAttribute("houses",houses);
model.addAttribute("mapOfImages",mapOfImages);
```

So now within thyemleaf view template I can:

```
<div data-th-each="house : ${houses}">
        <h3 data-th-text="${house.title}"></h3>
        <div data-th-each="image : ${mapOfImages.get(house.houseId)}">
          <h5 data-th-text="${image.fileName}"></h5>
          <h5 data-th-text="${image.type}"></h5>
        </div>
 </div>
```

The database being used is Mongodb which has two independent collections: house and image i.e. there are no embedded collections and the only thing that tie up an image to a house is the houseId property on image.

Comment: Please share actual classes and a code snippet demonstrating what you've tried.

Comment: I think this article should help you out http://javasampleapproach.com/reactive-programming/reactor/reactor-convert-flux-into-list-map-reactive-programming, also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517762/can-i-use-block-method-of-flux-returned-from-spring5s-webclient and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039497/reactor-fluxmyobject-to-monolistmyobject

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You basically want to transform a stream of `House` objects into a stream of `Image` objects.

So, use `flatMap()` which converts `Flux<Flux<T>>` (or `Flux<Mono<T>>`) into `Flux<T>`.

```
Mono<List<Image>> images = houseService.findAllHouses() // returns Flux<House>
  .flatMap(house -> imageService.findByHouseId(id)      // returns Flux<Image>
                        .filter(image -> "yes".equals(image.getCover()) && ... )) 
  .collectList();                                       //returns Mono<List<Image>>
```

Its OK to use `collectList()` here, because you most possibly want to convert `images` into a single `Mono<ServerResponse>` object anyway:

```
return images.map(imageList -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                       .body(fromObject(imageList)));
```

Also, I recommend reading [Project Reactor reference](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html) about [when to use which operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#which.values).

---

**EDIT:**

So, you want a `Mono<Map<String, Collection<Image>>` instead. My answer would depend whether the `Image` class has a reference back to the `House`. It's still OK if it doesn't, the answer would be more verbose though.

I'll describe the hard way, where `Image` doesn't contain the `House` id. We need sth., which links the list of images belonging to a specific house. You can define a class for this purpose or just use `reactor.util.function.Tuple2`. Having that, we can just use `collectMap()`:

```
Mono<Map<String, Collection<Image>>> images = houseService.findAllHouses()
     .flatMap(house -> imageService.findByHouseId(id)
                           .filter(...)
                           .map(image -> Tuples.of(id, image)))
     .collectMultiMap(tuple -> tuple.getT1(), 
                      tuple -> tuple.getT2());
```

Of course, if you have a reference back to the `House`, then you could omit the `map()` again and use `collectMultiMap` directly:

```
...
    .collectMultiMap(image -> image.getHouseId(), image -> image);
```

Comment: Thank you Murat. Getting there but still not there. In order to clarify I added more text at the end of my question.

Comment: OK, please see the last edit. I think `collectMultiMap()` can do what you want. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Looks good. I will use that to implement. Most images have houseId property but a few images such as street view or city view type images will have houseId property blank but such images will still be collected for that house to show associated street view or city images when that house is displayed in the view. Thank you will update soon after I have worked on it.

Comment: Sure, hope that helps