# How to convert List<Mono<String>> into Flux<List<String>>?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor, spring-reactive

```
List<Mono<String>> responses = apiCall()
```

I would like to get `Flux<String>` to await all mono-s from list.

How could I achieve it ?

### P.S.

I've found similar question but I need vice versa operation https://stackoverflow.com/a/44040346/2674303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Flux.mergeSequential()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#mergeSequential-java.lang.Iterable-) and [`Flux.collectList()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--)

```
Mono<List<String>> list = Flux.mergeSequential(apiCall()).collectList();
```

Comment: at this case mono.subsribe function argument will be invoked with List<String> argument when all mono will be resolved ?